# JPA Why only this @ManyToOne returns null?

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, jpa, orm, openjpa

### UPDATE

I find something interesting

When I run JPQL like this

```
SELECT s FROM STUDENTS s WHERE s.community=:community
```

then this issue happens, but this query runs fine and returns all necessary fields

```
SELECT s FROM STUDENTS s WHERE s.id=:id
```

meaning if there is an inner join with its child field, then somehow the value of the other field get missing. I got both native query and both returns all necessary field values. Must be openjpa dismiss the school fields some how when native query returns

Yes, `Community` and `School` both may map to another entity, but how come that could cause this strange behavior? I am kind of mad with OpenJPA

---

I have spent hours to fix this strange issue

there is a class contains several @ManyToOne relation

```
public class Student{

// Relationships

@NotNull
@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
private Teacher teacher;

@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@Column(name = "SCHOOL_ID")
private School school;

@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
private Club club;

@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
private Bus bus;
    ....
}
```

Each of the many side has a definition like this(Only give the School entity as it has the issue):

```
public class School implements Institution{
// Relationships

@OneToMany(mappedBy="school")
private List<Student> students= new ArrayList<Student>();
    ....
```

}

The problem here is when I try to get All students for a certain age:

```
SELECT s FROM STUDENTS s WHERE s.age=:age
```

I can clearly see the all other @ManyToOne fields' value ONLY EXCEPT `school`, and in Oracle database the school_id field clearly stored with correct data which map to the correct entry in School table

So what could be the possible reason for this situation?

I am using Spring MVC3 + Openjpa + Roo

Comment: Why not this -->    @OneToMany(mappedBy="school")
private List<Student> students;

Comment: @Ashish Thanks do you mean to take off `= new ArrayList<Student>();`? I bet that's not the issue. I tried but it doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Your `school` mapping should use a `@JoinColumn` annotation (not a `@Column` annotation):

```
@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "SCHOOL_ID")
private School school;
```

Comment: Thanks I tried too but doesn't help. Actually initially I didn't use `@Column` or `@JoinColumn` so it shouldn't matter but it still return null. I am thinking there might be some stupid configuration by me cause this issue, but all i get is everything in the post... sigh..